# Run-Time Check Failure #0: Why am I getting this and what does it mean?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

In my program (it is for a homework assignment), I load in a model which is a bunch of vertices and normals etc into a struct I have. When drawing it, I pass the model to a function `void drawModel(Model model)`. Doing that gives me this error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

I was looking around, and one answer seemed to be that it was because what I'm passing is too large and it's messing up the compiler. So I tried changing it so the `drawModel` function accepts a pointer to the struct (which I should've done to begin with...), but as soon as I access it in the function I get that error.

How can I get around this? And why is this happening?

Here's the entire function

```
void drawModel(Model * model)
{
    int i, g; //i is the main iterator, g keeps track of what part we're on
    int edge; //The current edge we're on
    g = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < (model->faceCount); i++) //This is just to test why it's occuring
    {
    }
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, model->vertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, model->normals);
    for(i = 0; i < (model->faceCount); i++) //Right here is where i get the error
    {
        if(i == model->parts[g])
        {
            //Set colour to the part colour

            g++;
        }

        glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, model->faces[i].edges, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            model->faces[i].edge);
    }
}
```

Note: I've never used GL vertex arrays before, this is my first attempt.

I was calling drawModel like so: `drawModel(&plane);`

Comment: Show us how you call `drawModel`, and the definitions of everything that appears on that line.

Comment: I think this might actually be more of an OpenGL question

Comment: Jeff: How you *call* it.

Comment: I'll put that on there, but I figured out the problem, it was glNormalPointer. It doesn't take the first argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was

```
glNormalPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, model->normals);
```

It should've read

```
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, model->normals);
```